# innerHTML does not overwrite

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to create a HEX code generator and display it on a heading but the problem is it doesnt overwrite the text inside the heading instead it only placed adjacent to it.

```js
let hexGenerator = {
 result: '',
 characters: 'ABCDEF0123456789',
 hexColor: function() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   this.result += this.characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * this.characters.length));
  }
  return this.result;
 }
}

window.onload = () => {
 document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'HEX VALUE: #' + hexGenerator.hexColor();
 })
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="demo">HEX VALUE: #</h1>
  <button>Click Me!</button>
</body>
```

Comment: because your variable never is reset..... It always has the last generated value in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`element.innerHTML = ...` does overwrite.

`result += ...` does not overwrite.

Thanks for providing a minimum example. Add a `this.result = ''` will reset the value for each click.

```js
let hexGenerator = {
  result: '',
  characters: 'ABCDEF0123456789',
  hexColor: function() {
    this.result = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
      this.result += this.characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * this.characters.length));
    }
    return this.result;
  }
}

window.onload = () => {
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'HEX VALUE: #' + hexGenerator.hexColor();
  })
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="demo">HEX VALUE: #</h1>
  <button>Click Me!</button>
</body>
```

That being said, there's no reason to create a hexGenerator object here. You could just use a simple function:

```js
let hexColor = () => {
  let characters = 'ABCDEF0123456789';
  let result = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * characters.length));
  return result;
};

window.addEventListener('load', () =>
  document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () =>
    document.getElementById('demo').textContent = 'HEX VALUE: #' + hexColor()));
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="demo">HEX VALUE: #</h1>
  <button>Click Me!</button>
</body>
```

Edit:: per comment, here's how you'd do this with [classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes):

```js
class Generator {
  constructor() {
    this.characters = 'ABCDEF0123456789';
  }

  hexColor() {
    let result = '';
    for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++)
      result += this.characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * this.characters.length));
    return result;
  }
}

let gen = new Generator();

window.addEventListener('load', () =>
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () =>
      document.getElementById('demo').textContent = 'HEX VALUE: #' + gen.hexColor()));
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="demo">HEX VALUE: #</h1>
  <button>Click Me!</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. Well I could create it using simple function but I'm trying to learn OOP so thats why :P

Comment: For learning purposes, look into classes, a nice syntax overlay that is similar to actual classes and other languages. The raw object prototype stuff from 'old' JS isn't useful or similar to anything you'll actually use.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let hexGenerator = {
 result: '',
 characters: 'ABCDEF0123456789',
 hexColor: function() {
        this.result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   this.result += this.characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * this.characters.length));
  }
  return this.result;
 }
}

window.onload = () => {
 document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'HEX VALUE: #' + hexGenerator.hexColor();
 })
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="demo">HEX VALUE: #</h1>
  <button>Click Me!</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You're using compound assignment in your loop for your `result` value. Instead try creating a new variable within your hexColor function and assign a new value to `result` using that.

```js
let hexGenerator = {
 result: '',
 characters: 'ABCDEF0123456789',
 hexColor: function() {
    let hex = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   hex += this.characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * this.characters.length));
  }
    this.result = hex;
  return this.result;
 }
}

window.onload = () => {
 document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'HEX VALUE: #' + hexGenerator.hexColor();
 })
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="demo">HEX VALUE: #</h1>
  <button>Click Me!</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

When calling `hexGenerator.hexColor();`, `this.result` still holds the value of the function calls before.

Reset `this.result`at the beginning of `hexGenerator.hexColor();` resolves your issue:

```js
let hexGenerator = {
 result: '',
 characters: 'ABCDEF0123456789',
 hexColor: function() {
        this.result = '';   // <===== Reset value
  for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
   this.result += this.characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * this.characters.length));
  }
  return this.result;
 }
}

window.onload = () => {
 document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = 'HEX VALUE: #' + hexGenerator.hexColor();
 })
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h1 id="demo">HEX VALUE: #</h1>
  <button>Click Me!</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This will solve your problem. I have added a `<span>` element as well as the `ID` on your header parts.

**JS**

```
let hexGenerator = {
    result: '',
    characters: 'ABCDEF0123456789',
    hexColor: function() {
        this.result = '';   // <===== Reset value
        for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            this.result += this.characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * this.characters.length));
        }
        return this.result;
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
        document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = hexGenerator.hexColor();
    })
}
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
  <h1>HEX VALUE: #<span id="demo"></span></h1>
  <button>Click Me!</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!